# How can I cover this large square hole from a bad gas stove vent installation?

Tags: exterior, siding

I'm removing a gas heating stove that a previous owner did an absolutely expert job installing. Upon removing the exterior vent baffle, I discovered that, instead of cutting a circular vent hole, he cut a square hole and filled around the vent with twelve cans of spray PU foam.

What is my play for covering up this hole? My siding is wooden clapboard. This is a pretty non-visible area so I'm not terribly concerned about aesthetics. I was considering trimming the PU foam then taking some aluminum flashing, bending it to follow the siding, and screwing/caulking/painting. Is there a better way?

[image: clusterf*** of an installation.]

Comment: Was there anything aesthetically wrong with simply leaving the vent in place (and possibly plugging it)?

Comment: The pipe coming from the vent was too long to allow drywall to be installed.

Comment: Could just cut it off...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically a square hole was appropriate here, but then a steel wall thimble should've been used to keep adequate clearance to combustibles. Even insulated double-wall pipe shouldn't be in direct contact.

Anyway, "best" is subjective. I've done just what you describe with aluminum sheet, but since you have wood siding it shouldn't be difficult to cut back the boards and replace the sections to the corner. I'd repair the sheathing while the siding is opened up. Then insulate to suit.